# Можно ли употреблять шампунь для здоровых волос, если волосы нездоровы?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Все время попадаются на глаза выражения "шампунь для здоровых волос",  "упражнения для красивой фигуры" и т. п. Грамотно ли так писать? Ясно, что имеются в виду шампунь для оздоровления волос и упражнения для получения красивой фигуры. По-моему, шампунь для здоровых волос - это шампунь, который предназначен для здоровых волос, то есть его опасно употреблять, если волосы нездоровы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У самого предлога "для (чего-то)" такое значение (= направленное на что-то, с целью получения чего-то) существует и вполне распространено. Ну смотрите, если вам дарят что-то со словами "Для прекрасного настроения", вы не будете требовать замены на "опрекраснивание"?

У Кузнецова это, видимо, третье значение.

> 3. Указывает на цель, причину, основание совершения действия;
>      ради.Стараться для семьи. Сделать что-л. для пользы дела. Жить для себя. 
>      Сказать что-л. для смеху. Работать для общего блага.

Другое дело, что с шампунем, как вы и отметили, получается явная двусмысленность.

Потому что у того же Кузнецова есть и "шампунь для сухих волос" - и это главное значение предлога "для". Так что я бы поостерегся с подобными формулировками.

В отношении нормальной фигуры... Да наверное, тоже. Хотя тут не столь очевидная двусмыслица.

Но с другой-то стороны, рекламщиков и маркетологов тоже можно понять. Не напишешь же "для больных волос" или "для жирной фигуры".

Comment: "Для больных" звучит непривлекательно. Но писали же раньше:  "для укрепления волос". И с указанием проблем: "для ослабленных волос", "для ломких волос", "для сухих волос", "для жирных волос".

Comment: @М_Г - *для укрепления волос* - Так это же другое дело. Так и сейчас пишут. Но у нас нет этого смысла.

Answer (score 3):

Я понимаю фразу "шампунь для здоровых волос" буквально: шампунь, предназначенный для ухода за здоровыми волосами. По-моему, иного толкования и быть не может. Есть шампунь для ломких волос, для окрашенных волос, для повреждённых волос и т.д. Всё предельно ясно.

Comment: Да нет... Это именно "чтобы стали здоровыми". Это у простых людей "иного не может быть", а у рекламщиков - запросто.

Comment: Печально, коли так. Надо что-то делать...

Comment: Если рекламщики имели в виду оздоровление, то психологически они промахнулись (не учли давно сложившийся ряд назначений разных шампуней): воспринимается это как синоним "для нормальных".

Answer (score 1):

А как еще говорить?

Шампунь для укрепления волос? Грамотно, но **результат (здоровые волосы!) не обозначен**. Шампунь для получения здоровых волос? **Очень длинно**. Шампунь для здоровья волос? Как-то  странно говорить о здоровье отдельных частей тела (волос, рук, ног, головы).

**Вот и  используется один вариант**: шампунь (**предназначен**) для сухих волос и шампунь (**предназначен для получения**) здоровых волос. Соответственно,  приходится привыкать к разному значению одинаковых грамматических форм.

Comment: А чем плох вариант: шампунь для оздоровления волос, для укрепления волос? Ради красоты фразы жертвуем содержанием? Другое дело, многим в голову не приходит, что такое употребление не совсем корректно.

Comment: Серж, вариант-то хорош, да рекламщикам не подходит. Им надо заложить информацию в голову покупателя, а она должна быть краткой и содержательной: покупаешь их шампунь - имеешь здоровые волосы.  Известный психологический прием: обозначить  цель, результат, это главное. А потом, разве мало у нас в языке ононимичных форм, например: режем овощи (чем?) ножом и режем (как?) кубиками. Никого это не удивляет.

Comment: Sibylla, да, вы правы, рекламщиком не подходит. Но, думаю, они просто не задумывались над содержанием.

Comment: Наверное, задумывались, это же их хлеб  Думаю, что рекламные тексты сочиняют образованные люди  и от правил могут отступать преднамеренно.  Им не правила нужны, а  необычность, эффектность, эмоции. Возможно, в языке появляется новый стиль, который можно назвать рекламным, поэтому очень уж  печалиться  и "что-то делать" не стоит.